# Does producing TOTP tokens weaken the stored secret? How much?

Tags: authentication, multi-factor, totp, authenticator

I am using Google Authenticator as a second factor on some sites, (including my Google Account).

Every now and then I need to produce a token to log in.

**If some attacker received those tokens over time, would they become able to guess the internal secret (seed) for the TOTP in Google Authenticator**, thus being able to produce tokens for themselves?

How many tokens wouldy the need for a reasonable chance to log in, given they have the username/password already?

Comment: @Tensibai soory. I linked a bad answer.

Comment: @Jakuje NP, another [related one](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/42677/122317) I think